# Running a shiny python app from a script with `reload`

Tags: python, py-shiny

I was trying to run the example python shiny app directly from a script

```
"""Test shiny app."""

import argparse

from shiny import App, render, ui

app_ui = ui.page_fluid(
    ui.input_slider("n", "N", 0, 100, 20),
    ui.output_text_verbatim("txt"),
)


def server(input, output, _session):
    @output
    @render.text
    def txt():
        return f"n*2 is {input.n() * 2}."


app = App(app_ui, server)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Parse args passed into the Shiny app")
    ap.add_argument("--host", help="URL of host", default="127.0.0.1")
    ap.add_argument("--port", help="Port to use", type=int, default=8888)
    ap.add_argument("--reload", help="Enable auto-reload", action=argparse.BooleanOptionalAction, default=True)
    args = ap.parse_args()

    app.run(host=args.host, port=args.port, reload=args.reload)
```

When I run this script from a python environment which has shiny installed as

```
python test_app.py
```

I see the following error

```
WARNING:  Current configuration will not reload as not all conditions are met,please refer to documentation.
WARNING:  You must pass the application as an import string to enable 'reload' or 'workers'.
```

It works well if I set `reload=False`. Is there a workaround for this?

(EDIT: Fixed argparse issue pointed out by @relent95 in the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to run a shiny app directly inside an application main module.

If you insist, use the `run_app()` like the following. But I'm not sure it will not be broken in the future.

```
# This is the test_app.py file.
...
app = App(app_ui, server)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
    from shiny import run_app
    run_app('test_app:app', host=args.host, port=args.port, reload=True)
```

As a side note, you incorrectly implemented the `--reload` option. See [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action).